# Show/hide div not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am having an issue getting my div's to show on select from the drop down menu,  I am getting `$ is not defined`  I have adjusted my code to not have duplicate ids.  When I load the page it shows all 3 divs but as soon as I select an option from the drop down they all go and hide.

*JS:*

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#requiredOption').change(function(){
        $('#newwebsiteDiv,#websiteredevelopmentDiv,#otherDiv').hide();
        $(this).find('option:selected').attr('id') + ('Div').show();
    });
});
```

*HTML:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Template 2011</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_assets/css/style.css">
</head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div id="logo">Template Here</div>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                        <li><a href="quote.html">Free Quote</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Showcase</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
        </header>
                        <section id="content">
            <h1>Free Quote</h1>
                <p>Please fill out the below questionnaire to receive your free web development quote</p>
                    <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                        <select name="requiredOption" id="requiredOption">
                            <option id="pleaseselect" value="pleaseselect">Please Select Your Required Quote</option>
                            <option id="newwebsite" value="newwebsite">New Website</option>
                            <option id="websiteredevelopment" value="websiteredevelopment">Website Redevelopment</option>
                            <option id="other" value="other">Other</option>
                        </select>
                        <p><input type="submit" value="submit"></p>
                    </form>
                        <section id="newwebsiteDiv">
                            <p>New Website</p>
                        </section>
                            <section id="websiteredevelopmentDiv">
                                <p>Website Redevelopment</p>
                            </section>
                                <section id="otherDiv">
                                    <p>Other</p>
                                </section>

</section>
            <section id="sidebar">
        <div id="box_one">
            <p>Box One</p>
        </div>
        <div id="box_two">
            <p>Box Two</p>
        </div>
        <div id="box_three">
            <p>Box Three</p>
        </div>
        </section>      
            <footer>
                <p>This is the footer</p>
            </footer>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="_assets/js/js.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: move your JS files in the HEAD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the jquery and js file import thing is ok;
first,your code not include any element contains id "select".your hide code should like 'evan'

> $('#newwebsite,#websiteredevelopment,#other').hide(); 
>   so your code should like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#requiredOption').change(function(){
        $('#newwebsiteDiv,#websiteredevelopmentDiv,#otherDiv').hide();
        var targetDiv=$(this).find('option:selected').attr("id")+"Div"
        $("#"+targetDiv).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: I have just said a few words :)  But it still is not showing the div for some reason.

Comment: A shot from chrome with your above code, will not change http://cl.ly/1Y1h1o0B10143E103Q0d

Comment: sorry!above code i hide select item,i should hide your div ,try modify 'hide' line $('#newwebsiteDiv,#websiteredevelopmentDiv,#otherDiv').hide();

Comment: I saw that you updated @coonooo but its still as above have cleared and reloaded cache

Comment: targetDiv, last string 'div' should be 'Div'

Comment: I have adjusted that its still showing as above strange @coonooo

Comment: are you able to put it up on jsfiddle.net?  its being strange for me :(

Answer (score 4):

Put the jQuery include in the `<head>`.

also:

> ```
>     $('#newwebsite','#websiteredevelopment','#other').hide();
> ```

should be:

```
    $('#newwebsite, #websiteredevelopment, #other').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks I have done this but its still not working and it should work with the <script> in the footer, also it shows all of my values in chrome but only one in FF 6 why?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#requiredOption').change(function() {
    var divToHide = "#" + $(this).val() + "Div";
    $(divToHide).show()
      .siblings('#newwebsiteDiv, #websiteredevelopmentDiv, #otherDiv')
        .hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: that works fine but when I load the page it shows the #newwebsiteDiv would you display:none in css?

Comment: If you want the sections to be hidden I would absolutely set it in css. Also, it would be better to replace `'#newwebsiteDiv, #websiteredevelopmentDiv, #otherDiv'` with `'section'` in my code, but I wasn't sure what you would want.